# Pinch zoom on image C#/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, pinchzoom

I'm creating a simple slideshow on UWP using C#/XAML 
I've got a problem with the zoom on image. 
In fact when I zoom, if I try to move the picture, it moves, but when I remove my hand, the picture is coming back to a "default position" like it was linked to a border or something like this...

Here is sample of my XAML

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Margin="0,280,0,0" Height="1490" Background="Black">
    <FlipViewItem Height="1620" Width="1080">
        <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled">
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="Images/test.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="1610" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </FlipViewItem>
```

Do you have any idea of what can cause this ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of your page is becoming smaller than the image itself.

Have a look at this blogpost which gives a good solution:
http://igrali.com/2015/07/16/why-is-my-zoomable-scrollviewer-snapping-the-image-to-the-left/

Comment: Oh ok i'm gonna look this solution 
I find another way to solve it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by adding horizontal and vertical scroll bar option on auto